# Failure to Accept Socket Connection in Java

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I'm trying to make a simple program with a server and client, passing text strings back and forth. I'm having trouble making the connection. I have a test printing line right below the socket accept line and it never prints, so I assume the problem is there, but I'm not sure how to do a more thorough check.

I have written this program in Eclipse if that makes a difference.

This is the server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HW2Q1S {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {
        //connection
        ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(7654);
        Socket skt = srvr.accept();
        System.out.println(skt.getPort());

        //data xfer
        BufferedReader sIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter sOut = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);

        //string receiving
        int count = 1;
        String msg = "";

        while((msg = sIn.readLine()) != null) {
            while(count < 11) {
                msg = sIn.readLine();
                System.out.println("Received: "+ msg);
                String returnMsg = msg.toUpperCase();
                System.out.println("Capped: "+ returnMsg);
                sOut.write(returnMsg);
                count++;
            } 
        } //end of read from client in while loop
        if (count == 10) {
            System.out.println("Max reached.");
        }
        srvr.close();
        return;
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error caught: " + e);
    }

} // end of main
} // end of class
```

And this is the client:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HW2Q1C {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String capped = "";
    String temp = "";

    try {
        //make the connection
        Socket skt = new Socket("localhost", 7654);
        BufferedReader cIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter cOut = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);

        //send 11 strings
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            temp = Stringer();
            cOut.write(temp);
            System.out.println("Sending: " + temp);

        }

        //receive server strings
        while(cIn.readLine() != null) {
        capped = cIn.readLine();
        System.out.println("From server: "+ capped);
        }

        skt.close();
    } // end of connection try block

    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
    }

} //end of main

static String Stringer() {
    String msg, alpha;
    msg = "";
    alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        msg += alpha.charAt(rnd.nextInt(25));
    }
    return msg;
}
 } //end of class
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess an exception occurs, whats the stacktrace? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: That's what I thought, but there's nothing in the console. It's completely empty.

Comment: I just ran your program and as far as I can see is the connection itself fine. srvr.accept() waits until a client connects (which it does correctly) Maybe this is of additional help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: `"Whoops! It didn't work!\n"` is a stupid way to report an exception. You should log the exception itself, preferably its stack trace. If the answer you accepted was really the solution, you didn't describe your problem accurately. You claimed that the line after `accept()` wasn't reached. If that was true, the solution you accepted could not possibly have made any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found your problem.
You should use `println` instead of `write`. I am quite sure the problem is that write does not send an actual line `string + \n` and therefore the server cannot read a line.
I modified your example a little bit to make it easier to test and understand, but this works for me:

Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            //connection
            ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(7654);
            Socket skt = srvr.accept();
            System.out.println(skt.getPort());

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));

            String msg = "";
            while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Received: " + msg);
            } //end of read from client in while loop
            srvr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error caught: " + e);
        }

    } // end of main
} // end of class
```

Client:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 7654);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                out.println(Stringer()); //<-- println instead of write
            }
            socket.close();
        } // end of connection try block
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.toString());
        }

    } //end of main

    static String Stringer() {
        String msg, alpha;
        msg = "";
        alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            msg += alpha.charAt(rnd.nextInt(25));
        }
        return msg;
    }
} //end of class
```

ServerOutput:

> Received: scnhnmaiqh
>   Received: tuussdmqqr
>   Received: kuofypeefy
>   Received: vghsinefdi
>   Received: ysomirnfit
>   Received: lbhqjfbdio
>   Received: qhcguladyg
>   Received: wihrogklfi
>   Received: tipikgfvsx
>   Received: fmpdcbtxqb
>   Received: yujtuefqft